# iOS Swift - CGSizeFromString throws CGSizeZero

Tags: ios, swift, view, collections, cgsize

I have this function which is used to set size from String length. 
Something like that - [Swift iOS - Tag collection view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159938/swift-ios-tag-collection-view).

First item in categoriesItems is "Age"

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        var cellWidth : CGSize = CGSizeFromString(self.categoriesItems[indexPath.row].name);

        return cellWidth
}
```

Comment: I don't think `CGSizeFromString` is what you're looking for. Indeed it is used like so : `var size : CGSize = CGSizeFromString("{320,568}")` to create a `CGSize` from a specific formatted string and not based on the string length.

Comment: Yes. You're right. But this is not answer what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the width of text use the following code

```
let text = self.categoriesItems[indexPath.row].name
let rect = text.boundingRectWithSize(constraintSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)], context: nil)
return rect.size.width
```

where `constraintSize` is some arbitrary size in which you wish to constraint your text

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSString`s `sizeWithAttributes` function to do this. Then you cast it as it as a `CGSize`. This size is the size of the text, so if you want there to be padding around it, just add a value to the width and height of the size:

```
let string: NSString = self.categoriesItems[indexPath.row].name
let size: CGSize = string.sizeWithAttributes(nil) // Enter font/size attributes here
return size
```